# cant get biterr function to work in octave

Tags: linux, octave, fedora

I am using octave 4.0.3 in a fedora 24 system.
I wanted to use the function biterr, but it was not there along with octave, so i obtained it from octave communication package and copied to location of other already available .m files.

/usr/share/octave/4.0.3/m/signal

I have faced this issue with other functions as well but the above procedure always saved me. But with biterr function I am facing one more issue, it displays the error

'**errcore**' undefined

I obtained **errcore**.cc file also but don't know where to copy it so that biterr function works, ( I tried in same path but didn't help)

Where is the location i should copy **errcore**.cc ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't manually copy files from octave-forge packages to octave. Use `pkg install apackage.tar.gz` from the Octave prompt instead

Comment: If you started with the Fedora Octave package, just install the Octave packages provided by Fedora. `dnf install octave-communications`